# Microstrategy 10.2 Repopulate Relate Tables

Tags: microstrategy

I have a problem, with no errors or nothing wrong in logs.

I'm trying to repopulate relate tables with Enterprise Manager but the tables aren't being loaded correctly, only the default value appears.

The mechanism I'm using is simple: if a date is bigger then another, the process executes.

But even when I manually changed the dates with a SQL query, the process doesn't give me any results.

I also created a data load with the option to repopulate and still no changes.

Even tried to apply the fix to the 10.1 version and still nothing... (https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB268380-In-MicroStrategy-10-Enterprise-Manager-Lookup-tables-in)

If any of you have any idea I'd be grateful.